# Qt creator remote debugger

Tags: qt, qt-creator, remote-debugging

I am trying to hook my beagle board to qt creator 2.3.1 running on Ubuntu Linux. I tried to find a good tutorial for this and found that qt documentation has nothing on this.(I do not understand why there is a feature which documentation does not bother to explain how to use). Could some one please explain how to do this?

Comment: What is a beagle board? What feature is not in the documentation? Are you talking about a feature of Qt or a feature of a beagle board?

Comment: sorry for the late reply but beagleboard is a OMAP3 embedded device and I am trying to use qt creator remote debugger on this.

Comment: Is [this project](http://beagleboard.org/project/TCF+agent+port/) of any interest?

Comment: With a lot of help I figured this, I will post an answer when I have hands on confirmation with better details.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and would really appreciate any information you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cross compile qt for beagle board [This post should be at help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120479/qt-embedded-compile-error-fixing-error-no-such-instruction-error)
2. Open Qtcreator and go to project tab and select the tools -> options. Select Linux devices and add the device. For this beagle board need to be attached. For the option of host name it is required to add the ip address of the device. Other than this other fields are self explanatory. Test Button would assist in checking the device addition.
3. Then in the project settings under Run configuration in the Deployment drop-down box select Build tar ball and install.
4. At this point tool chain and the cross compiled qt version should be added in the qt creator.
5. Basic procedure should be done by now and when the application is run it should be deployed on the device at the specified location.