# Problems cross compiling Qt 4.7 from source for ARM

Tags: c++, linux, qt, embedded, arm

I'm trying to cross-compile Qt 4.7.1 from source, here are some notes on my setup:

1. my expected output is the shared object libraries that are required to be present in order to run a Qt application.
2. My target platform is a TI AM335x processor which is of the ARM Cortex-A8 architecture.
3. My development platform is a x86 64-bit Ubuntu virtual machine

My understanding of how this should work is that I download the toolchain for my target platform (this is the [Linaro](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Sitara_Linux_SDK_GCC_Toolchain) toolchain from TI), I download the source code for [Qt 4.7.1](http://download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.7/), I set the mkspec to use my tool chain, run `configure`, then just need to run `make`/`make install` and I should be able to find all the `.so`'s where I told it to install to. I'm having a lot of problems getting this idea to work however.

---

First I downloaded the TI SDK version: ti-sdk-am335x-evm-06.00.00.00 which has the arm tool's at: 
`[root_install_dir]/linux-devkit/sysroots/i686-arago-linux/usr/bin`

I updated my `$PATH` with that directory:

> mike@mike-VirtualBox:~$ echo $PATH
>   **/home/mike/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-06.00.00.00/linux-devkit/sysroots/i686-arago-linux/usr/bin**
>   :/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/bin:/home/mike/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:
>   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/mike/bin

I then created my own mkspec based on the closest example:
`cp -R [qt_install_dir]/mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++/ [qt_install_dir]/mkspecs/qws/linux-am335x-g++`

and I modified the `linux-am335x-g++/qmake.conf` to point to the tools from the TI sdk:

```
# modifications to g++.conf
QMAKE_CC                = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
QMAKE_CXX               = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
QMAKE_LINK              = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++

# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR                = arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy
QMAKE_STRIP             = arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip
```

Then I ran a configure command:

> ./configure -prefix /home/mike/qt4.7.1_source/my_qt -embedded arm -platform qws/linux-x86_64-g++ -xplatform qws/linux-am335x-g++ -no-mmx -no-3dnow -no-sse -no-sse2 -no-glib -no-cups -no-largefile -no-accessibility -no-openssl -no-gtkstyle -fast -opensource

It runs for a while then completes and says it's ready to do `make`/`make install` at this point I run `make` and that's where it starts to fail:

> /home/mike/qt4.7.1_source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.1/bin/moc
>   -DQT_SHARED -DQT_BUILD_CORE_LIB -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT3_SUPPORT -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_FAST_OPERATOR_PLUS -DQT_USE_FAST_CONCATENATION -DELF_INTERPRETER=\"/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2\" -DHB_EXPORT=Q_CORE_EXPORT -DQT_HAVE_NEON -DQT_NO_DEBUG -I../../mkspecs/qws/linux-am335x-g++ -I. -I../../include -I../../include/QtCore -I.rcc/release-shared-emb-arm -Iglobal -I../3rdparty/harfbuzz/src -I../3rdparty/md5 -I../3rdparty/md4 -I.moc/release-shared-emb-arm kernel/qobject.h -o .moc/release-shared-emb-arm/moc_qobject.cpp arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c
>   -include .pch/release-shared-emb-arm/QtCore -pipe -fno-exceptions -mfpu=neon -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_SHARED -DQT_BUILD_CORE_LIB -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT3_SUPPORT -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_FAST_OPERATOR_PLUS -DQT_USE_FAST_CONCATENATION -DELF_INTERPRETER=\"/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2\" -DHB_EXPORT=Q_CORE_EXPORT -DQT_HAVE_NEON -DQT_NO_DEBUG -I../../mkspecs/qws/linux-am335x-g++ -I. -I../../include -I../../include/QtCore -I.rcc/release-shared-emb-arm -Iglobal -I../3rdparty/harfbuzz/src -I../3rdparty/md5 -I../3rdparty/md4 -I.moc/release-shared-emb-arm -o .obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qobject.o kernel/qobject.cpp
>  {standard input}: Assembler messages:
>   **{standard input}:1294: Error: selected processor does not support Thumb mode 'swp r6,r4,[r3]'** 
>   **make[1]:**  [.obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qobject.o] Error 1* 
> make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/mike/qt4.7.1_source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.1/src/corelib'
>   make: *** [sub-corelib-make_default-ordered] Error 2

So, the question... 
Why is the compiler complaining that the thumb mode is not supported? Since this is a cross compile tool chain for an *ARM* based processor, it *should be* supported. The fact that it's not makes me feel that `make` is somehow picking up the wrong version of g++.

Any thoughts on what went wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) instead or manual cross-compilation? See these [slides](http://elinux.org/images/2/2a/Using-buildroot-real-project.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> {standard input}:1294: Error: selected processor does not support Thumb mode **'swp r6,r4,[r3]'**
>
> Why is the compiler complaining that the thumb mode is not supported?

Note, the compiler is complaining about the `swp` instruction not being available for *thumb mode*.  Your CPU supports *thumb*, *thumb2*, and *ARM*.  The Cortex series deprecates the use of `swp` and prefers `ldrex/strex` pairs.

> Any thoughts on what went wrong and how to fix this?

You need to get gcc to define `__ARM_ARCH_7__`; this is done with either `-mcpu=cortex-a8` or the combination `-mtune=cortex-a8` and `-march=armv7-a` or what ever you like depending on how many types of boards you want **Qt** to run on.

In detail,  see [*qatomic_arm.h*](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/11ed361d1d66f011f6bc56d70d3adc4d235c3e52:src/corelib/arch/qatomic_arm.h) for where a sub-file is selected.  You have a very generic **ARM** selected (I guess), so you get [*qatomic_armv5.h*](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/11ed361d1d66f011f6bc56d70d3adc4d235c3e52:src/corelib/arch/qatomic_armv5.h)<sup>Note1</sup> where you can see the code around line 125.  The right file for your CPU is *qatomic_armv7.h*, which mainly just includes [*qatomic_armv6.h*](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/11ed361d1d66f011f6bc56d70d3adc4d235c3e52:src/corelib/arch/qatomic_armv6.h).  In this file you can find `ldrex/strex` which is the wholesome goodness that your `gcc` is requesting.

I also suggest you do not compile with *-fast*.  There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120479/qt-embedded-compile-error-fixing-error-no-such-instruction-error) where the OP says this solved his issue; but I think this is different.

You can try to pass `-armfpa` to configure.  `./configure -embedded arm --help` is useful.  `configure` appears to have selected *NEON*, so it seems to know you have a more advanced CPU (there is no *NEON* on an *armv5*, but this maybe a fault of `configure`).

For certain, you don't want the `swp` code and the `ldrex/strex` is preferred for your system, even if `swp` could somehow work.  I would at least resolve this.  Alter the `-xplatform qws/linux-am335x-g++` to update `-mcpu` or possibly pass an explicit `-D__ARM_ARCH_7__`.  You can get a list of defines with [`arm-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a8 -dM -E - < /dev/null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines), to verify that the `__ARM_ARCH_7__` is being defined.  It looks like it is `moc` failing, so maybe the `-D__ARM_ARCH_7_` solution will be needed.

You might also try to alter `-mthumb` in the compiler option.  It is probably best to use `-mcpu=cortex-a8` and `-mthumb` for your system, if you can get that to compile/build.  Omitting `-mthumb` will make the code slightly larger.  You might also try `-Os`.  For some reason, I have **huge** builds with other optimizations and more recent `gcc` versions.  It appears to be due to some C++ feature as normal 'C' doesn't behave this way; but this may just be my compiler.  I looked and believe it is the exception tables, but I never confirmed anything and moved on.  I am sure you are aware of how long Qt takes to compile.

**Note1:**  The *qatomic_armv5.h* code is fairly confused and newer `gcc` or *binutils* will choke even when this is the correct file to use.

```
 asm volatile("swpb %0,%2,[%3]"
: "=&r"(ret), "=m" (*ptr)
: "r"(newval), "r"(ptr)
: "cc", "memory");
```

This specifies some *inline assembler* parameters which are never used.  Not to mention the condition codes are not used, etc.

```
asm volatile("swpb %0,%1,[%2]"
             : "=r"(ret)
             : "0"(newval), "r"(ptr)
             : "memory");
```

will compile with newer `gcc` and *binutils*.  It also uses less registers and is optimal for the way *Qt* is currently using it; there maybe cases where `ret` needs to be preserved to compare to `newval` but it is just a user space *spin lock* currently.

The bracket `[x]` is a memory operand register and must be different than the other two parameters for a valid `swp`.  I believe the first form was used to stop `%0` from being the same as `%3`.  The 2nd form avoids this by making `%0` and `%1` the same, so `%2` must be different.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful input, I'll remove `-fast` for posterity and look into some of those other flags. This is my first time doing a Qt cross compile, AFAIK adding `QMAKE_CFLAGS` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` to the qmake.conf is the correct way to add in flags to be passed to the actual `make` (ie that's the correct place to pass `-marm`, `-mthumb`, etc). Do you know if that is correct?

Comment: Yes, those seem correct.  There are a million variables, but mostly they are just aggregated.  [Advanced Qmake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html), [Linux journal cross](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/cross-compiling-qt), [Building Qt for embedded](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_for_Embedded_Linux), etc.  I was pretty sure I had a really good reference on *mkspec*, but maybe it is for Qt5.x and I can't find it now...

Comment: Err, these guys say `-embedded armv7` where [they have the same problem](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7304).  This is probably a better solution than mucking with *mkspecs*, if it works; just verify that this passes good `-mcpu` or `-march` values, so your code is optimal (as well as compiling).

Answer (score 1):

the answer by usr: artless noise did in fact fix my issue, but since I want to make sure there is a very clear trail for myself (if needed) or others, I want to state exactly what the fix was:

First, I updated my `.configure` command to:

`./configure -prefix /home/mike/qt4.7.1_source/my_qt -embedded arm -platform qws/linux-x86_64-g++ -xplatform qws/linux-am335x-g++ -no-mmx -no-3dnow -no-sse -no-sse2 -no-glib -no-cups -no-largefile -no-accessibility -no-openssl -no-gtkstyle -opensource -qt-mouse-tslib`

The only difference from the question's configure command is the removal of the `-fast` option.

Then in my the linux-am335x-g++/qmake.conf file, I added a few command line options:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS= -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS= -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8
```

With these two change I can now see everything build and install Qt4.7.1 successfully.

I also tried Qt4.8.5 and everything works the same except one more option has to be added to the ./configure command:

```
-no-pch
```

This is to avoid an error regarding a: .pch
directory and files in side showing "No such file or directory"