# Cross-compiling Qt quick app for embedded linux ARM board

Tags: c++, qt, qtembedded

I have a ubuntu app developed using the ubuntu SDK (Qt Quick QML with c++). I'm a newbie, so please excuse me if my question sounds stupid.

Now, I want to cross compile this app for an embedded linux ARM board which has QtEmbedded installed.

I've been searching through the net and found that './configure' should be used.

I wasn't able to figure out how to get started. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Start by installing a cross-compiler. Verify that it works by cross-compiling a hello world prohram (text terminal, no graphics) and running it on the target board. Once you have done that, try building your program for Ubuntu natively using `configure`. Once you have it working, read [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
Do you mean I need to install the same gcc toolchain that is on the target board onto my dev system?

Comment: No, you need a *cross* toolchain. The board has a *native* toolchain. Ubuntu should have ARM cross toolchain available through apt.

Comment: Did you read the [official crosscompilation guide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-crosscompiling.html) ? Also, take a look at [this related question for an example of configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268833/problems-cross-compiling-qt-4-7-from-source-for-arm)