# How can I stop gcc from emitting swap{b} on newer ARM cpus?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, arm

I'm compiling [DCP-O-Matic](http://dcpomatic.com) on a Raspberry Pi 2 and am getting the following warning:

```
/tmp/ccu6rDcg.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccu6rDcg.s:4208: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
```

I've passed "-mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon" to the compiler, but I still get the warnings. I'm pretty sure there is something in the Linux kernel that makes this warning irrelevant, but I would really like to solve this.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268833/problems-cross-compiling-qt-4-7-from-source-for-arm/21288430#) has a lot of good information, but I can't seem to find the right switches to prevent the warnings. I've verified that there is no explicit assembler code using swp{b}.

Can anyone recommend the best way to clear these warnings? I really am kind of anal about compilation warnings. ;) I figure if there's a warning, there's a fix.

To clarify, I'm interested in how to get the gcc toolchain to emit the correct LDREX/STREX instructions, rather than swap{b}.

Comment: What I would do is to make build verbose. If it is `make` try V=1, and see full toolchain invocation for that particular line. High chance you'll see the culprit. In worst case there might be a inline assembly in your source files where `swp` was explicitly used.

Comment: `swp` is explicitly used in ccu6rDcg.s at line 4208. David doesn't try to stop using `swp`, he tries to disable the warning message, which is relevant on cortex-A8 as it is an ARM v7a, [excepted if this assembly code is run in a non preemptible context](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/CJHBGBBJ.html). Therefore, I would rather modify the code to use exclusive monitor than trying to disable the warning.

Comment: @Jacen ccu6rDcg.s is an artifact of compilation, that doesn't mean it is explicitly used in code base he is trying to compile. That swp could be produced due to a macro, intrinsic etc.

Comment: I would imagine that this is due to some in-line assembler macro.  The **best** way is to find what source is causing it and eliminate it.  The assembler file will have 'line' and 'file' stuff in it.  Save the temporary and look around/above line 4208.  It should point you to a macro or source line.  *I've verified that there is no explicit assembler code using swp{b}.* if this is true, then the compiler is buggy.  An system header include may have a macro with inline assembler `swp`.

Comment: What platform are you building on? Raspbian? Based on which Debian?

Comment: Why version of GCC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the warning with -mno-warn-deprecated. A quick grep of the source code doesn't seem to show a use of inline asm, so perhaps it is in a header file of some library.

Incidentally, the Raspberry Pi 2 uses a Cortex-A7 processor, and you should get better performance if you build with -mcpu=cortex-a7 instead of -mcpu=cortex-a8.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had forgotten about the no-warn flag. However, I'm more interested in how to get gcc to emit the correct LDREX/STREX instructions, rather than swap{b}.